# Event target logging as undefined or expected value randomly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating an app using the weatherAPI as a project to learn ReactJS. I've created a method to console.log a property of an event target on click. However when I trigger the on click event the value logged in the console will log as the expected value only 20% of the time. The other times it will log as undefined.

Main app code -

```
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      temperature: undefined,
      city: undefined,
      country: undefined,
      humidity: undefined,
      description: undefined,
    }

    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
  }

  getWeather = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const cityId = e.target.value;
    console.log(cityId);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Header />
        <Button city="City1" getWeather={this.getWeather} />
        <Button city="City2" getWeather={this.getWeather} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Button component code -

```
export default function Button(props) {
    return (
        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" name={props.city} value={props.city} onClick={props.getWeather}>
            <h2>{props.city}</h2>
        </button>
    )
}
```

If is spam click either buttons, undefined will be logged most of the time with either City1 or City2 being logged sporadically such as below

```
>(29) undefined
>(11) City1
>(32) undefined
>(2)  City2
```

Comment: Try using `event.currentTarget` rather than `event.target`. Might be related to event bubbling.

Comment: Thank you Gavin, it seems to work perfectly with that change